# How to combine tree and wc -l?

Tags: linux, bash, tree, ls, wc

I have folder `base_dir` with subfolders, each subfolder contain .jpg images, I want output similar to `tree -L 1 base_dir`, but with number of jpg images next to subfolder name, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

This will output somwhat similar:

```
find  base_dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | 
xargs -0 -n1 sh -c 'echo "$1 $(find "$1" -name "*.jpg" | wc -l)"' --
```

For each directory in base_dir output the directory name and the count of files named `*.jpg`. Example output:

```
base_dir/b 2
base_dir/a 1
base_dir/d 3
base_dir/c 0
```